# Convert daily data in pandas dataframe to monthly data

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has daily stock data in it:

```
       Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000    
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000   
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000
```

I'd like to calculate monthly returns using the last day of each month in my df above. I'm guessing (after googling) that resample is the best way to select the last trading day of the month. But this doesn't seem to work:

```
df.set_index('Date')  
m1= df.resample('M')
print(m1)
```

get this error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

So I think that means the set_index isn't working?

I've also tried:

```
df= df.reset_index().set_index('Date')  
m1= df.resample('M')
print(m1)
```

But I get the same error message as above. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: `set_index` is not an in-place operation without the `inplace` flag.  That's why your first attempt doesn't work, you aren't actually changing your dataframe.

Comment: Try `df.set_index('Date').resample('M').last()`

Comment: tried df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.resample('M')
but still get same error. Also tried your earlier suggestion, df.set_index('Date').resample('M').last() but no luck so far

Comment: for my imports I have import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

Comment: You need to first convert the index to datetimeindex. df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index). If Date is a column, df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: Hi Vaishali, have those 2 lines of code in there, but while the output is showing date as the index now,  it's still printing every single date, instead of the last day of the month

Comment: can you print df.dtypes?

Comment: sure, it prints:                                                            AAPL    float64
NFLX    float64
INTC    float64
dtype: object

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

# import stock price data
df = pd.read_csv('etc)


df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime (df['Date'])


df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.resample('M').last()
print(df)

Comment: You are converting index to datetime before setting Date column to index. Correct order should be df = pd.read_csv('etc') 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.resample('M').last()

Comment: phew! that worked Vaishali, thank you so much for your patience with me! really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your index is not a DatetimeIndex. But you can make it a DatetimeIndex:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('1M').mean()
#                 AAPL      NFLX    INTC
#Date                                   
#2008-01-31  26.248857  3.577429  23.566
```

Comment: what about mean or sum for only one column of dataframe ?