# Change monthly data to daily in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where the date is the first day of the month

```
date           spend      category
1/Feb/2018     565          Red
1/Dec/2019     674          Blue
1/Feb/2019     878          Green
```

I'd like to create extra rows in the dataframe to include every day in the month, whilst duplicating the other data

```
date           spend      category
1/Feb/2018     565          Red
2/Feb/2018     565          Red
.
.
.
27/Feb/2018     565          Red
28/Feb/2018     565          Red
1/Dec/2019     674          Blue
2/Dec/2019     674          Blue
.
.
.
30/Dec/2019     674          Blue
31/Dec/2019     674          Blue
1/Feb/2019     878          Green
2/Feb/2019     878          Green
.
.    
27/Feb/2019     878          Green
28/Feb/2019     878          Green
```

I have a long way of doing this but is there a quick couple of lines that can achieve the same thing?

thanks alot,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert daily data in pandas dataframe to monthly data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997339/convert-daily-data-in-pandas-dataframe-to-monthly-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resample by months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) with [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html), last add [`DataFrame.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('m')
df = df.set_index('date').resample('d').ffill().to_timestamp()
print (df)
            spend category
date                      
2018-02-01    565      Red
2018-02-02    565      Red
2018-02-03    565      Red
2018-02-04    565      Red
2018-02-05    565      Red
          ...      ...
2019-12-27    674     Blue
2019-12-28    674     Blue
2019-12-29    674     Blue
2019-12-30    674     Blue
2019-12-31    674     Blue

[699 rows x 2 columns]
```